# Java End of File Exception

Tags: java, unexpectendoffile

I am writing a simple instant messaging program using JavaFX and have encountered an an End Of File exception and after hours of debugging I cannot find a solution.

My program is written in two parts, the client and the server. They send serialized objects to each other containing all the necessary information to complete the required action. I was adding additional features to my program when I started getting this error in the server. I have since removed all of the additional code but am still getting this error message. I don't understand why I'm getting this error as neither the client nor the server are sending a message meaning there's no file to reach the end of??

I comment out the line where I call the method "sendMessage()" and that seems to solve the issue but I need this method to work.

Bellow is a copy of the server class

```
package instachatfx.server;


public class ServerMain {

    private static HashSet<ObjectOutputStream> writers;
    private static ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        writers = new HashSet<>();

        try (ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(Constants.
            while (true) {
                new Handler(listener.accept()).start();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ServerMain.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

    private static class Handler extends Thread {

        private Socket socket;

        private ObjectInputStream input;
        private OutputStream os;
        private ObjectOutputStream output;
        private InputStream is;

        private User user;
        private String code;

        public Handler(Socket socket) throws IOException {
            this.socket = socket;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                is = socket.getInputStream();
                input = new ObjectInputStream(is);
                os = socket.getOutputStream();
                output = new ObjectOutputStream(os);

                while (socket.isConnected()) {
                    System.out.println("Waiting for packet...");
                    Packet inputmsg = (Packet) input.readObject();
                    if (inputmsg != null) {
                        switch (inputmsg.getHeader()) {
                            case REGISTER:
                                System.out.println("Case: REGISTER");
                                registerUser((User) inputmsg.getContent());
                                break;
                            case LOGIN:
                                System.out.println("Case: LOGIN");
                                loginUser((User) inputmsg.getContent());
                                break;
                            case CODE:
                                System.out.println("Case: CODE");
                                if (((String) inputmsg.getContent()).equalsIgnoreCase(code)) {
                                    Constants.getDBManager().createNewUser(user);
                                    loginUser(user);
                                } else {
                                    sendMessage(PacketHeader.INCORRECT_CODE, "Incorrect code");
                                }
                                break;
                            case MESSAGE:
                                System.out.println("Case: MESSAGE");
                                sendToAll(inputmsg);

                                System.out.println(((Message) inputmsg.getContent()).getUser().toString() + ": " + ((Message) inputmsg.getContent()).getContent());
                                break;
                            default:
                                throw new HeaderNotFoundException("Server has no case for: " + inputmsg.getHeader().name());
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (SocketException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ServerMain.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ServerMain.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (HeaderNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ServerMain.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (EOFException ex)
                Logger.getLogger(ServerMain.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ServerMain.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } finally {
                closeConnections();
            }

        }

        private void sendToAll(Packet msg) throws IOException {
            System.out.println("Send to all: " + msg.getHeader());
            ((Message) msg.getContent()).setUsers(users);
            for (ObjectOutputStream writer : writers) {
                writer.writeObject(msg);
                writer.flush();
                writer.reset();
            }
        }

        private void sendToOthers(Packet msg) throws IOException {
            System.out.println("Send to others: " + msg.getHeader());
            ((Message) msg.getContent()).setUsers(users);
            for (ObjectOutputStream writer : writers) {
                if (output != writer) {
                    writer.writeObject(msg);
                    writer.flush();
                    writer.reset();
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Logs in a user
         * @param u the user to be logged in
         */
        private void loginUser(User u) {
            try {
                User us;
                if ((us = Constants.getDBManager().loginUser(u)) != null) {
                    System.out.println("User found in database");
                    user = us;
                    writers.add(output);
                    users.add(user);
                    LoginMsg msg = new LoginMsg(user, users);
                    sendMessage(PacketHeader.LOGIN_SUCCESSFUL, 
                    sendToOthers(new Packet(PacketHeader.MESSAGE, new Message(user.toString() + " has joined the chat", new User("SERVER", null))));
                } else {
                    sendMessage(PacketHeader.LOGIN_FAIL, "Please check email and password");
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ServerMain.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

        private void registerUser(User u) throws IOException{
            user = u;
            if (Constants.getDBManager().checkDeuplicateEmail(u.getEmail())) {
                sendMessage(PacketHeader.EMAIL_ALREADY_USED, "The email address " + u.getEmail() + " has already been used to make an account");
                System.out.println("Email already exists");
                return;
            } else if ((code = sendVerificationEmail(u)) == null) {
                sendMessage(PacketHeader.EMAIL_NOT_VALID, "There was an error sending the email  to "
                        + u.getEmail() + ". Please make sure the email is correct");
                System.out.println("email failed sending");
                return;
            }

            sendMessage(PacketHeader.WAIT_FOR_CODE, "Type in code in email");
        }

        /**
         * Sends an email to the user to verify that it is correct
         *
         * @param u The user to send the email to
         * @return null - the email failed sending <br>
         * random sting - the email successfully sent using this verification
         * code
         */
        private String sendVerificationEmail(User u) {
            String code = RandomString.getAlphaNumericString(10);
            if (Constants.getSendEmail().sendEmail(u, code)) {
                return code;
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * Sends a packet to only the client
         *
         * @param packetHeader for the client to tell how to read in the message
         * @param msg the message for the client
         */
        private void sendMessage(PacketHeader packetHeader, Object msg) throws IOException {
            System.out.println("Send to client: " + packetHeader);
            Packet message = new Packet(packetHeader, msg);
            //ERROR OCCURS HERE
            output.writeObject(message);
            output.flush();
        }

        private void closeConnections() {
            if (user != null){
                users.remove(user);
            }

            try {
                sendToAll(new Packet(PacketHeader.MESSAGE, new Message(user.toString() + " has left the chat", new User("SERVER", null))));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ServerMain.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

            if (output != null){
                writers.remove(output);
            }
            if (is != null) {
                try {
                    is.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(ServerMain.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
            if (os != null){
                try {
                    os.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(ServerMain.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
            if (input != null) {
                try {
                    input.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(ServerMain.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: here is the stacktrace

Nov 11, 2019 12:44:21 PM instachatfx.server.ServerMain$Handler run
SEVERE: null
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:2950)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1534)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:427)
    at instachatfx.server.ServerMain$Handler.run(ServerMain.java:83)

Comment: `while (socket.isConnected())` is not a valid test. It *is* connected, because you connected it, or accepted it, and that state will remain with the socket forever, even if you close it personally. It does not reflect the state of the *connection*. That is represented by, err, `EOFException`, which means the peer has closed the connection, or by any other `IOException` (other than `SocketTimeoutException` when reading) which all mean the connection is broken and the socket must be closed. All you need to do is change to `while (true)` and catch `EOFException` earlier.

Comment: NB You only need to close `output`. Closing any stream of a socket closes the other streams and the socket, and closing anything that extends `FilterInputStream` or `FilterOutputStream` closes the wrapped stream, and you should close the outermost output stream to ensure it gets flushed, which therefore closes everything else.

Comment: NB (2) The `EOFException` occurs at `readObject()`, not at `writeObject()`. You might have got an error at the latter, probably a 'connection reset', but never an `EOFException`.

Comment: And the stack trace you edited in proves it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't understand why I'm getting this error ...

You are getting the error because one end has closed its output stream ... or the entire socket.  This could be the result of an explicit close, or because the application has exited.

> ... as neither the client nor the server are sending a message ...

The application (client or server) is attempting to *read* a message, but no message will be forthcoming because the other end has closed the stream that this end is trying to read from.

> ... meaning there's no file to reach the end of.

Your logic is incorrect.  The "file" that is referred to is the stream referred to above.  If you close the writing end, the reading end sees an end of stream / end of file if it tries to continue reading.

---

It looks like a pseudo-anonymous commenter has identified an error that probably explains your problem.  The `Socket.isConnected()` method cannot be used to test if a socket is still connected.  The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#isConnected()) states:

> ```
>  public boolean isConnected()
> ```
>
> Returns the connection state of the socket.
>
> Note: Closing a socket doesn't clear its connection state, **which means
>   this method will return true for a closed socket (see `isClosed()`) if
>   it was successfully connected prior to being closed**.
>
> Returns:
>       `true` if the socket **was** successfully connected to a server

(Emphasis added ...)

---

If you need more help, please provide a proper [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and be sure to include the full stacktrace for the exception or exceptions.

Comment: Yea.  I thought that was the case.  But a stacktrace would disprove that the OP's theory about where the problem was occurring.

Comment: Thank you for your help. That has clarified what exactly the issue is. And thank you for the link to minimal reproducible example. I've edited the question to include the stacktrace and yes it does occur at readObject(). You suggest that the client program has closed the connection?

Comment: Thank you so much! I went through the client and found that it was forcibly closing the connection

Comment: @JimmyT1601 No, it was closing the connection normally. If it had 'forcibly' closed it you would have got 'connection reset'. Kind of you not to acknowledge my input at any stage.

Comment: @user207421 Sorry, bad choice of words. And I’m sorry I didn’t acknowledge you! I implemented the changes you suggested as well. Thank you :)